# Debugging a docker compose mariadb healthcheck

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm trying to add an healthcheck in a mariadb service but it then prevents the client connection to the server, showing the message:

```
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (0)
```

The connection can be established and everything runs fine without the following healthcheck:

```
healthcheck:
  test: /usr/bin/learnintouch/db-health-check.sh
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 3
```

... with the healthcheck behaving as expected:

```
root@428b1e6c7c1a:/usr/bin/learnintouch/www/folkuniversitet# /usr/bin/learnintouch/db-health-check.sh
+ /usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -u root -pxxxxxx -e 'show databases;'
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| db_engine          |
| db_learnintouch    |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

The initial working service configuration is:

```
  mysql:
    image: localhost:5000/mariadb:10.1.24
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
    networks:
      - learnintouch
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/database/data:/usr/bin/mariadb/install/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/logs:/usr/bin/mariadb/install/logs"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 10s
```

The failing service configuration is:

```
  mysql:
    image: localhost:5000/mariadb:10.1.24
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=xxxxxx
    networks:
      - learnintouch
    volumes:
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/database/data:/usr/bin/mariadb/install/data"
      - "~/dev/docker/projects/learnintouch/volumes/logs:/usr/bin/mariadb/install/logs"
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 5s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 10s
    healthcheck:
      test: /usr/bin/learnintouch/db-health-check.sh
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
```

At server startup, the `mariadb` log is exactly the same, with or without the healthcheck, and ends with:

```
2017-12-29 10:27:48 139873749194560 [Note] /usr/bin/mariadb/install/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.24-MariaDB'  socket: '/usr/bin/mariadb/install/tmp/mariadb.sock'  port: 3306  Source distribution
```

Here is the `db-health-check.sh` bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

/usr/bin/mysql/install/bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -u root -pxxxxxx -e "show databases;" || exit 1
```

I'm on Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.05.0-ce
 API version:  1.29 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   89658be
 Built:        Thu May  4 22:10:54 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

UPDATE:

There were a few issues in fact, which together made the whole thing puzzling.

The first one was that the `db-health-check.sh` file was sitting in the client application container, and thus could not be found by the service database container, when this latter needed to perform its healthcheck.

The second one was that the `db-health-check.sh` file used a wrong path for its `mysql` client `/usr/bin/mariadb/install/bin/mysql`.

The third one was that the `db-health-check.sh` file used a wrong hostname in its connection, wrongly using `mysql` instead of `localhost`.

The fourth one was that the `root` user could not connect on the `1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'` as it should not have any password as in `/usr/bin/mariadb/install/bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h localhost -u root -e "show databases;" || exit 1`.

After correcting these points, the application can start and run fine even with the healthcheck in place.

The one thing that blurred the lines even further, was that the service is not available until the first healthcheck has passed successfully. Indeed I configured an heatlcheck as:

```
healthcheck:
      test: exit 0
      interval: 60s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
```

with the container state showing this at first:

```
"Health": {
    "Status": "starting",
    "FailingStreak": 0,
    "Log": []
}
```

and the application was stillnot able to connect to the service until after the first interval of 60s expired and the healthcheck being successful.

I should therefore have a short interval time so as to have the application not wait for too long to be available.

Comment: Did you try with `-h localhost`?

Comment: Yes I did, and also with 127.0.0.1, and I have the very same error.

Comment: Again, without the health check, the database is accessible from other containers, and the application runs just fine.

Comment: Does the health check failure show any reason? Try `docker inspect <containerid>`

Comment: The inspect show a `"Running": true` `"Status": "running"` `"ExitCode": 0`.

Comment: Could the container be stuck in a deadlock startup ? Say, if it waits for the healthcheck to be successful before making the service available... the healthcheck would then fail as the service is not yet available...

Comment: The `"Health" "Log" "Output"` also shows the same error message `"+ /usr/bin/mariadb/install/bin/mysql --protocol=tcp -h mysql -u root -pxxxxxx -e 'show databases;'\nERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (-2)\n+ exit 1\n"`